# How to add data from one grid view to another grid view using a button Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm attempting to add details from one gridview to another gridview on the same page; however I'm not see the gridview (not visible). Not sure exactly what is causing that because visible is set to true in properties window.

```
protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    DataRow drow;
    DataTable dt = SetDataTable();
    drow = dt.NewRow();
    //GridView1.Rows.Add(1);
    int row = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
    drow["Customer Name"] = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Text;
    drow["Invoice #"] = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text;
    drow["Invoice Qty"] = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2].Text;
    //drow["Salary"] = textBox4.Text.Trim();
    dt.Rows.Add(drow);
    BindGrid(dt);
    btnDelete.Visible = true;

}

private DataTable SetDataTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        DataColumn dcol = new DataColumn("Customer Name", typeof(System.String));
        dt.Columns.Add(dcol);
        dcol = new DataColumn("Invoice #", typeof(System.String));
        dt.Columns.Add(dcol);
        dcol = new DataColumn("Invoice Qty", typeof(System.String));
        dt.Columns.Add(dcol);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return dt;
}
private void BindGrid(DataTable dt)
{
    try
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;

        }
        else { }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `GridView2.DataBind();`? And you have empty `catch` blocks. So if there is an error you would not know it.

Comment: Sorry I missed that out; however the data not being added to second gridview and i'm not getting any error after I added error message to the catch block

Comment: @VDWWD; why would the data not add to the second gridview